# Node.js flash messages not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, flash-message

Can someone please tell me why the flash messages are not working in my case?

This is how I'm trying to use it:

This is a part of my `app.js`:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var session          = require('express-session');
var exphbs           = require('express-handlebars');
var passport         = require('passport')  
var RedisStore       = require('connect-redis')(session)
var redis            = require('redis').createClient();

app.use(session({
     secret: "I can haz working sessions?",
     store: new RedisStore({ client: redis })
}));

app.use(flash());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
  res.locals.errors = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

This is how I'm trying to use it in my controller:

```
module.exports.storageCreatePost = function(req, res) {
  req.flash('error', "Test");
  res.redirect('/ftp/create');
})
```

This is my `hbs` view where the message is supposed to render:

```
  {{#if error}}
    <p class="alert alert-warning">{{error}}</p>
  {{/if}}
```

It successfully redirects me to `/ftp/create` but the flash message is not rendered..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by replacing `res.locals.errors` with `res.locals.error`

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.get('/ftp/create',fun...` controller,try to render the flash messages like,

```
resp.render('view_fle',{
 error:req.flash('error') 
......
....
```